# How is it possible to aggregate messages from Kafka topic based on duration (e.g. 1h)?

Tags: apache-kafka, streaming, aggregation

We are streaming messages to a Kafka topic at a rate of a few hundred per second. Each message has a timestamp and a payload. Ultimately, we would like aggregate one hour worth of data - based on the timestamp of the message - into parquet files and upload them to a cheap remote storage (object-store).

A naive approach would be to have the consumer simply read the messages from the topic and do the aggregation/roll-up in memory, and once there is one hour worth of data, generate and upload the parquet file.

However, in case the consumer crashes or needs to be restarted, we would lose all data since the beginning of the current hour - if we use `enable.auto.commit=true` or `enable.auto.commit=false` and manually commit after a batch of messages.

A simple solution for the Consumer could be to keep reading until one hour worth of data is in memory, do the parquet file generation (and upload it), and only then call `commitAsync()` or `commitSync()` (using `enable.auto.commit=false` and use an external store to keep track of the offsets).

But this would lead to millions of messages not being committed for at least one hour. I am wondering if Kafka does even allow to "delay" the commit of messages for so many messages / so long time (I seem to remember to have read about this somewhere but for the life of me I cannot find it again).

Actual questions:

a) is there a limit to the number of messages (or duration) not being committed before Kafka possibly considers the Consumer to be broken or stops giving additional messages to the consumer? this seems counter-intuitive though, since what would be the purpose of `enable.auto.commit=false` and managing the offsets in the Consumer (with e.g. the help of an external database).

b) in terms of robustness/redundancy and scalability, it would be great to have more than one Consumer in the consumer group; if I understand correctly, it is never possible to have more than one Consumer per partition. If we then run more than one Consumer and configure multiple partitions per topic we cannot do this kind of aggregation/roll-up, since now messages will be distributed across Consumers. The only way to work-around this issue would be to have an additional (external) temporary storage for all those messages belonging to such one-hour group, correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure Kafka Streams with a TimestampExtractor to aggregate data into [different types of time-windows](https://developer.confluent.io/learn-kafka/kafka-streams/windowing/)

> into parquet files and upload them to a cheap remote storage (object-store).

Kafka Connect S3 sink, or Pinterest Secor tool, already do this